# 7segment blink when the button is pressed

Tags: arduino-uno, ir

I have programmed an IR remote control along with an LED and an 8bit 7segment on an Arduino Uno.
the segment displays the number I press via the remote, and the LED turns on and off
here's my code:

```
case 16738455:
  Serial.println(0);
  if (oldvalue == results.value){
    on(num0);
    delay(1000);
    on(num00);
    delay(1000);
    oldvalue = results.value;
  }
```

oldvalue stores the last value pressed, which is the DEC value of the buttons, num0 displays the number zero, and num00 turns all the segments off.
I want the 7segment to blink again when I press the same button again.
Can anyone help me with this? 
Thanks

Comment: You have to provide more code if you want some help. What is the code for the `on` function? What else is inside your `loop()` function?

Comment: The code is long, this is the dropbox link to it:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/haw498jlwmol75z/IRwith7segment.ino

Comment: Please put it on pastebin - dropbox is too transient.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/9iYgyrd5

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to not worry about blinking as a piece of code, ie. remove those delays (I hate blocking code) and instead, if you are currently receiving a signal from the remote, do not display any number (or display your `num00`). Once the value is received and processed, then display that number.

This way, whilst ever the remote button is down, the display will blank out, and the number will appear as soon as the number is released. If it's the same number, then you will see the number, see a blank display, and then see the same number again. Obviously, if it's a different number, the new number would be displayed.

Since most people would only press the remote button for 100-1500ms, it should give you a nice delay anyway.

Finally, you may encounter some flashing if you process the data so quickly and the remote auto repeats. This could be handy if that number is processed multiple times by the receiving unit. The flashing would indicate that that is the case. If that is undesired, implement a simple state machine.

**edit:** your pastebin code came up whilst I was writing this answer. Having a quick look at your code, I would suggest that in the section:

```
if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
  //receiving data? display nothing
  on(num00);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  Serial.println(results.value, DEC);
  irrecv.resume();
  delay(100);
  int oldvalue = results.value;
  switch(results.value){
    case 16738455:
      Serial.println(0);
      num2display=0;      // make sure to declare this var somewhere
      //if (oldvalue == results.value){
      //  on(num0);
      //  delay(1000); 
      //  on(num00);
      //  delay(1000); 
      //} else {   // I think you missed an else here
      //  oldvalue = results.value;  
      //}
      //on(num0); 
      //delay(1000); // you don't want such large blocking delays
      irrecv.resume();
      break;
    case 16724175:
      Serial.println(1);
      num2display=1;       // add this for each section
      irrecv.resume();
      break;
      . . .
  }
}
else{
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  on(num2display);
}
```

you only set the variable to be displayed, but display `num00`. Then in the else, you can display that number

Comment: Responding to a button being released is a little tricky with IR remotes. Unlike a physical button, you don't get a steady signal while the remote button is held. Rather, you get a repeating signal, which could end up looking like lots of presses in quick succession.

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield I did think of that after the fact (or towards the end of the answer), but that could be easily avoided: you would know the pause between transmissions, set a `timeStart` flag, and don't display before `timeStart+timeLag`. Resetting this at the beginning of each new repeated burst would ensure it only appears at the end of the transmission.

Comment: Thank you for your help Madivad
With all respect but I don't think you understood the code well
Here's the youtube link to it's video and what it does:
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBlAdn1adMw)
When I press a button, the 7segment displays that number, but what I want is, when I press the same button twice, the 7segment should blink in the second time, all the segments turn off and on again